# Completely remove Notepad++

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, notepad-plus-plus

How to completely remove Notepad++ in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal?

I can't find it in Synaptic package manager, and don't know where is on system, but I can see an icon in Activity. It is probably not completely installed, because I can't open it.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Pilot6 with apt-get install

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't install it via `wine`?

Comment: Is it one of the alternatives from this link [7 Best Notepad++ Alternatives For Linux](https://itsfoss.com/notepad-alternatives-for-linux/)? For example, Is it a snap? Anyway, uninstall depends on the install.

Comment: If it's genuinely Notepad++, that would be worth putting in the title.

Comment: @sudodus Well, , maybe it's snap but anyway I get the error when I try to use a command from answer :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notepad++ (*notepad-plus-plus*) is a snap package in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To remove Notepad++ open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap abort --last auto-refresh  
sudo snap disable notepad-plus-plus   
sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus
```

Comment: I don't know why, but there is a bag with Notepad:  `error: cannot remove "notepad-plus-plus": snap "notepad-plus-plus" has "auto-refresh" change in progress`

Comment: I edited my answer with how to stop the "auto-refresh" change in progress. If that doesn't work remove the notepad-plus-plus snap directory with this command: `sudo rm -r snap/notepad-plus-plus`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this command to remove it while ignoring the "auto-refresh" progress:

```
sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus now
```